# Is it possible to see port details using pm2?

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

At present pm2 provides

```
App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu  │ mem       │ user │ watching
```

To the same header, can we add and see port number as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find the ports of all running pm2 apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53336086/where-can-i-find-the-ports-of-all-running-pm2-apps)

Comment: @TridevMishra - I am not looking for the solution from netstat, will pm2 provide that field as well is my question

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't list them, which I think is silly as it needs the port to start the node process off, so it has the info, this seems like "won't fix"
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/428