# How to get list nodejs processes/app port and path?

Tags: node.js, process, port, pm2

As a freelance SysAdmin/Developer  I need to  get/update existing app/web on the client server. Sometime I need to update existing NodeJS app that I don't know the port or the path.

If I want to know the port, I can do easily by find apache2/PHP app config using `apache2ctl -S` command. But it's difficult to find the nodeJS app path even I know the port.

Usually the node app is running using pm2. `pm list` only show list of processes name/command  like below:

```
root@lamp-s-4vcpu-8gb-sgp1-01:~# pm2 list
┌────┬────────────────────┬──────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name               │ mode     │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ memory   │
├────┼────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 11 │ .com               │ fork     │ 0    │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 6  │ DEV API            │ fork     │ 0    │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 0  │ balance Web        │ fork     │ 7    │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 4  │ balance queue      │ fork     │ 0    │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 9  │ index              │ fork     │ 133… │ online    │ 0.3%     │ 144.0mb  │
│ 10 │ index              │ fork     │ 21   │ online    │ 0.2%     │ 134.5mb  │
│ 12 │ index              │ fork     │ 13   │ online    │ 0.4%     │ 155.4mb  │
│ 7  │ longbgst           │ fork     │ 52   │ online    │ 0%       │ 40.0mb   │
│ 8  │ npm                │ fork     │ 220… │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 2  │ npm run staging    │ fork     │ 116… │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 1  │ old                │ fork     │ 0    │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 5  │ v-api dev          │ fork     │ 0    │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │
│ 3  │ develop API        │ fork     │ 358… │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │
└────┴────────────────────┴──────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
[PM2][WARN] Current process list running is not in sync with saved list. Type 'pm2 save' to synchronize or enable autosync via 'pm2 set pm2:autodump true'
```

and `pm2 show` command only show path not the port example:

```
root@lamp-s-4vcpu-8gb-sgp1-01:~# pm2 show 10
 Describing process with id 10 - name index
┌───────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ status            │ online                                  │
│ name              │ index                                   │
│ namespace         │ default                                 │
│ version           │ 1.0.0                                   │
│ restarts          │ 21                                      │
│ uptime            │ 2D                                      │
│ script path       │ /var/www/api-path-id/dist/index.js      │
│ script args       │ N/A                                     │
│ error log path    │ /root/.pm2/logs/index-error.log         │
│ out log path      │ /root/.pm2/logs/index-out.log           │
│ pid path          │ /root/.pm2/pids/index-10.pid            │
│ interpreter       │ node                                    │
│ interpreter args  │ N/A                                     │
│ script id         │ 10                                      │
│ exec cwd          │ /var/www/api-path-id                    │
│ exec mode         │ fork_mode                               │
│ node.js version   │ 11.15.0                                 │
│ node env          │ api_path_id                             │
│ watch & reload    │ ✘                                       │
│ unstable restarts │ 0                                       │
│ created at        │ 2020-11-16T03:29:39.945Z
```

Usually I need to look up using `pm2 show` command for each pm2 process to find the app path then got to the path and find the port on .env/config file. It's very take a long time if there are so many processes. Is any faster way to see list of running nodejs app with the port and path?

I tried commands from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53336086/where-can-i-find-the-ports-of-all-running-pm2-apps) answer but not returned path or process name like below:

```
root@lamp-s-4vcpu-8gb-sgp1-01:~# ss -tnlp | grep "node /"
LISTEN   0         128               127.0.0.1:6030             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("node /var/www/v",pid=26000,fd=25))
LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:6031             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("node /var/www/a",pid=26006,fd=25))
LISTEN   0         128               127.0.0.1:6039             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("node /var/www/a",pid=26013,fd=25))
root@lamp-s-4vcpu-8gb-sgp1-01:~#
root@lamp-s-4vcpu-8gb-sgp1-01:~# ss -ntlp | grep $(pm2 ls | grep "SITENAME" | awk '{print $10}') | awk '{print $4}'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

`ss -lntp | grep node` command show all port but it gives wrong path (maybe cutted/substr).

```
root@lamp-s-4vcpu-8gb-sgp1-01:~# ss -lntp | grep node
LISTEN   0         128               127.0.0.1:6030             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("node /var/www/v",pid=26000,fd=25))
LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:6031             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("node /var/www/a",pid=26006,fd=25))
LISTEN   0         128               127.0.0.1:6039             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("node /var/www/a",pid=26013,fd=25))
LISTEN   0         128               127.0.0.1:3001             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("node",pid=29886,fd=24))
root@lamp-s-4vcpu-8gb-sgp1-01:~# cd /var/www/a
-bash: cd: /var/www/a: No such file or directory
```

I need list of port and path(or atleast pm2 process name).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the ports of all running pm2 apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53336086/where-can-i-find-the-ports-of-all-running-pm2-apps)

Comment: The generic linux way is `ss -lntp | grep node`

Comment: @Matt still same, only show the port not the app path neither process name,  I need list of port and path(or atleast pm2 process name)

Comment: Does pm2 give you the OS pid? that's usually the way to link things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just learn some Linux commands to make this:

## METHOD 1  using`ss` without sorting (not recommended)

**Step 1 - Get the PIDs**

```
ss -lntp | grep node | cut -d "=" -f2 - | cut -d "," -f 1 - > pids.txt
```

Explanation:

1. `ss -lntp` will print the list of Socket Statistics.
2. `grep node` will print only node process/sockets.
3. `cut -d "=" -f2 -` will cut the output of command #2 using `=` as the delimiter and get the second column (`-f2`). example result is `26000,fd`
4. `cut -d "," -f 1 -` to remove `,fd` from command #3 and will cut the output of step #2 using `,` as the delimiter and get the first column (`-f1`). example result is `26000`
5. `> pids.txt` to save the output to pids.txt file.

**Step 2 - Get the Ports**

```
ss -lntp | grep node | awk '{ print $4 }' > ports.txt
```

Explanation:

1. `ss -lntp` will print the list of Socket Statistics.
2. `grep node` will print only node process/sockets.
3. `awk '{ print $4 }'` will print the fourth column, i.e. the one containing `0.0.0.0:6031`
4. `> ports.txt` to save the output to ports.txt file.

**Step 3 - Get the Paths from the PIDs**

```
ps -eLf | grep -Fwf pids.txt   | awk '!x[$2]++' | awk '{ print $11 }' > proc.txt
```

Explanation:

1. `ps -eLf` will print the list of Process status.
2. `grep -Fwf pids.txt` will print only pid/process number from pids.txt.(but its  still have so many duplicate main process)
3. `awk '!x[$2]++'` will filter only unique pid number only. the pid number is on 2nd column so use `$2`
4. `awk '{ print $11 }'` will print only 11th column. the path is on 11th column so use `$11`
5. `> proc.txt` to save the output to proc.txt file.

**Step 4 - Show list merged paths, ports and processes**

```
paste -d" " proc.txt ports.txt pids.txt
```

example output(same server as my question)

```
root@lamp-s-4vcpu-8gb-sgp1-01:~# paste -d" " proc.txt ports.txt pids.txt
/var/www/******/dist/index.js 127.0.0.1:6030 26000
/var/www/api-****-id/dist/index.js 0.0.0.0:6031 26006
/var/www/api.****.com/dist/index.js 127.0.0.1:6039 26013
/var/www/***-nuxt/node_modules/.bin/nuxt 127.0.0.1:3001 29886
```

can be simply to a line:

```
ss -lntp | grep node | cut -d "=" -f 2 - | cut -d "," -f 1 - > pids.txt && ss -lntp | grep node | awk '{ print $4 }' > ports.txt && ps -eLf | grep -Fwf pids.txt   | awk '!x[$2]++' | awk '{ print $11 }' > proc.txt && paste -d" " proc.txt ports.txt pids.txt
```

Maybe above commands can be improved, because I just learn today some commands like `ss`, `sort`, `paste`, `cut`, `awk` and `ps`

Above method work fine if list of pids from `ss` command is ascending sequence. But after try on another server above commands sometime does not work properly because the pids and path position can be swapped. So I tried to find out another way using sort like below:.

## METHOD 2  using `netstat` with PID sorting (recommended)

**Step 1 - Get the PIDs**

```
netstat -lntp | grep node | sort -k 7,7 |  awk '{ print $7 }' | cut -d "/" -f 1 - > pids.txt
```

**Step 2 - Get the Ports**

```
netstat -lntp | grep node | sort -k 7,7 |  awk '{ print $4 }' > ports.txt
```

**Step 3 - Get the Paths from the PIDs**

```
ps -eLf | grep -Fwf pids.txt   | awk '!x[$2]++' |  sort -k 2,2 | awk '{ print $11 }' > proc.txt
```

**Step 4 - Show list merged paths, ports and processes**

```
paste -d" " proc.txt ports.txt pids.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You will still need to issue a `pm2 list` command to get the `app_name` but this may give you a bit of help.

From the steps below you could set up a script to loop through each of the `PID's` returned from the command `pm2 pid`. This could be done by storing the output in a file `pid.text` and looping through.

```
pm2 pid > pid.text
```

**Step 1 - Get the PID**

```
TEST_PID=`pm2 pid app_name`
```

The `<app_name>` is the name of the pm2 process. The PID will now be in `TEST_PID`

**Step 2 - Get the path to the script**

```
TEST_PATH=$(ps -f -p $TEST_PID | grep -o "/.*")
```

This will use the PID obtained in step one and search for it in the entire list of processes. It then pipes this into `grep` where we only want the exact text match using the `-o` option. The pattern we are looking for is a `/` to indicate the start of a directory, followed by any character and we want everything after it.

**Step 3 - Get the port**

You can use the `netstat` command to get the information on the port. This is done by knowing the fact that we have the `PID`

```
PORT_TEST=$(sudo netstat -p | grep $TEST_PID | grep ':[0-9]*\s')
```

**Step 4 - Printing them out**

```
echo -e $TEST_PID'\n'$TEST_PATH'\n'$PORT_TEST
319
/home/warren/Ec2/EC2-QueryData/index.js
tcp6 0 0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:33979 TUDBNXJL63:52025 ESTABLISHED 319/node
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but it's only 1 process/app, my needs is all nodejs process/app